# Better way of doing check / Un-check checkboxes operation

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I was working on checkboxes operation using `jQuery`. I wrote a small snippet of code to make it work.

When I check `selectAll` check box, it should select all the checkboxes whilst when I un-check any of the check box it should un-check the "select all" one. And, the behavior should toggle.

Please check this code snippet [Check - UnCheck](http://jsfiddle.net/bnDqb/2/)

Somehow I'm not convinced with my code. Recommend if I can do it in a better way. TIA.

Comment: This type of questions belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), perhaps you better move it there?

Comment: @raina77ow oh! I wasn't aware of that portal. Anyway to automatically port it over there?

Comment: Not sure, perhaps some mod would be able to help. )

Comment: What the heck, I'd probably do [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/bnDqb/3/)...

Comment: @adeneo That's fantastic. Can you please explain how `.end()` is useful here?

Comment: First it selects the `first()` element and attaches a click handler, then `end()` is used to return to the original collection of elements to select all elements except the first etc.

Comment: @adeneo Please post the same in answers. Will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var elems = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    elems.first().on('change', function() {
        $(this).siblings(elems).prop('checked', this.checked);
    }).end().not(':first').on('change', function() {
        elems.first()
             .prop('checked', ((this.checked ? elems.length - 1 : elems.length) == $(elems)
             .filter(':checked').length));
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bnDqb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

1) you are searching the DOM every time you give

```
$(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
$(':checkbox :first').click()
```

etc...
instead store in a variable and use it

2) to get the no. of check boxes checked(u dont need to iterate and get count),

```
$(':checkbox').find(':checked').length
```

Comment: 3) `:checkbox` is deprecated, use `[type="checkbox"]`.